# A subgroup of special linear group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-groups

Does anybody know if the subgroup of diagonal and antidiagonal matrices of $SL(n,F)$ has been given a particular name?

By $SL(n,F)$

I mean $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$ with determinant 1. An $n \times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is antidiagonal if $a_{ij} \neq 0$ only if $i+j = n$.

Comment: $SL(n,F)$ is called the special Linear Group and In fact it's a subgroup of $GL(n,F)$ which is called the general Linear group (The group of all Invertible $n \times n$ Matrices with entries from the Field $F$)

Comment: @alkabary OP already know this,I think.

Comment: I've never seen a name for this group (not have I seen this group explicitly discussed before, even without a name).

Comment: @User3826143 Do you mean antidiagonal if $i+j=n+1$? Usually we do not start counting from $0$ in matrix notation.

Comment: I've never heard of names but the diagonal matrices are the kernel of this map $\det:\bigoplus_{i=1}^n GL(1,F)\rightarrow F^\times$ and the antidiagonal matrices are just these matrices with columns permuted by a matrix. So every matrix is generated by matrices of the above map and the permutation matrix.